# My discord bot won't stop spamming a respond to my command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I added a `//search` command to my bot. But when I tried running it, it gave me the options on where to search, but after a while, it starts spamming messages, and every time I type in the channel, it responds to that too. I haven't even answered the question yet and it immediately starts replying and giving me coins. Is there a way I can fix this? I've scanned the code multiple times and found no typos or errors; in fact, there are no errors logging into my console either.

[image: screenshot of my problem]

If the code is needed, here:

```js
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");

module.exports = {
  name: "search",
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  cooldowns: 30,
  description: "Search for some coin!",
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) {
    const locations = [
      "Dragonspine",
      "Windrise",
      "Qingyun Peak",
      "Mt. Hulao",
      "Mondstadt City",
      "Springvale",
      "Kamisato Estate",
      "Guyun Stone Forest",
      "Fort Mumei",
      "Watatsumi Island",
    ];

    const chosenLocations = locations
      .sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random())
      .slice(0, 3);

    const filter = ({ author, content }) =>
      message.author == author &&
      chosenLocations.some(
        (location) => location.toLowerCase() == content.toLowerCase()
      );

    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    const earnings = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100 + 1)) + 100;

    collector.on("collect", async (m) => {
      message.channel.send(`You found ${earnings} primogems !`);

      await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userID: message.author.id,
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            primogems: earnings,
          },
        }
      );
    });

    collector.on("end", (collected, reason) => {
      if (reason == "time") {
        message.channel.send("You ran out of time!");
      }
    });

    message.channel.send(
      `<@${
        message.author.id
      }> **Which location would you like to search?\n** Type the location in this channel\n \`${chosenLocations.join(
        "` `"
      )}\``
    );
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Super easy fix! The thing is you're creating a message collector on your `TextChannel` and **then** sending your message, of which location then user would want to pick, what you simply have to do is that move the collector to the `Message` object instead of `TextChannel` **after** sending the message.